How to let user choose location to save/create backup file in flutter
The old one I did before just a const path, i want to let them interact with view to select the location they want then put the file there.
Here is my old code:
  backupDB() async {
    var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    }
    var status1 = await Permission.storage.status;

    if (!status1.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    try {
      File ourDBFile = File(
          '/data/user/0/com.example.demo_sql_full/databases/Data.db');
      Directory? folderPathForDBFile =
          Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Database");
      await folderPathForDBFile.create();
      await ourDBFile.copy('/storage/emulated/0/Database/Data.db');
      print('đã backup');
    } catch (e) {
      print('-------- ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }

already search it but seem like nothing similar to my quest
Is there any way or I have to use somthing else?

you can use flutter_file_dialog package

what should i put into mime type if it is sqlite file ( .db) ?
or could you give me an example

I think that an optional parameter you can leave that parameter.

yeah. but im mean not sure what it for, can you name some type i can put in it ?

Mimetypes are typically used to identify the content type of a file for web servers or other applications that need to understand the file's format. some exmaples are image/jpeg, application/msword

so what if i just want to store it in user device storage only, do i have to care about this one ?

yeah you leave it. we are adding it when uploading images to firebase storage when we do not include the mime type when uploading the image to firebase storage the image is treated as a document and preview is not available in firebase storage.
